# dependent destroy not working with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

The plans won't be deleted after user is deleted.

Am i missing something ?

It supposed remove all plans belongs to deleted user.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Enum
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :plans, dependent: :destroy

class Plan
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: i tried to drop all the users, `User.destroy_all` but it didn't work

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FPersistable%2FDestroyable%2FClassMethods%3Adestroy_all) says "If no conditions are passed, the entire collection will be dropped for performance benefits. Fires the destroy callbacks if conditions were passed" so it claims that `User.destroy_all` doesn't call callbacks. The source and a quick test with 4.0.3 says otherwise though. Which specific Mongoid4 are you using? What happens if you `User.all.each(&:destroy)` instead?

Comment: I'm having similar issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: no, i'm trying to not use mongoid i found it doesn't support mongo really well. when i tried to use aggregation , it dosen't support `allowDiskUse` option ~~